# Redis Hardware Requirements and Alternatives

Tags: spring, session, redis

I have the following situation: i am using spring for a platform in productive form. Spring has Spring Sessions and allows HTTP-Session-Management independent of the docker container (sessions do not get lost). For session persistence i thought about a redis database.

The problem is: A redis for a productive environment would be way to expensive for what it does (i used the official recommendations:  https://docs.redislabs.com/latest/rs/administering/designing-production/hardware-requirements/ ).

Do i miss sonething? Is redis even a good idea here or simple an overkill? Do you know of any suitable alternatives?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a classical situation where you have read something that might have a certain appeal based on ration on one side and  the actual "need" to do it on other end.

The answer to "*Is redis even a good idea here or simple an overkill?*" is a tough one. Lets weigh the pros and cons, also, let us look at more specifics -

- What is the size of your application? and why do you want to move to Redis?

  - If your application is considerably big, no need to give two
    thoughts, proceed with your implementation
  - if your application is really small, reconsider other factors
- Where is your infra? is it on cloud? or is it on-prem?

  - if on prem how stable is your infra? without stable infra running redis would turn out to be a challenge.
  - If on prem - do you have a seperate admin team to manage? or do you
    have the resources to manage this yet another new system?
  - If on cloud - managing a redis would turnout to be really costly considering it runs in memory and does a lot of writes to FS. Please rethink from cost perspective.
- What is the mode of implementation?

  - is it containerized? if yes, how? Kubernetes with Volumes? or Kubernetes with PV-PVC?or bare-metal and docker volumes?
- How are  you setting up Redis?

  - Single node?
  - Master-Slave?
  - Redis Cluster?

### SUMMARY

I understand that the above set of questions might be overwhelming and a tough challenge to answer. I would recommend

- if your application size is huge - go for Master-Slave based Redis Setup using PV-PVC and use [BITNAMI HELM CHART](https://bitnami.com/stack/redis/helm)
- if your application is fairly small and if you still want to implement REDIS - go for docker container with Volume.

Please note - redis is great, just that we need to be specific about its implementation